# Why there is need to push django migrations to version control system

Tags: python, django, migration, django-migrations

This is a common practice that people working on django project usually push migrations to the version control system along with other code.

My question is why this practice is so common? Why not just push the updated models and everyone generate migrations locally. This approach can reduce the effort for resolving migrations conflicts too.

Comment: Related: (1) [**Why** push migrations to VCS? (`stackoverflow`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376092/why-there-is-need-to-push-django-migrations-to-version-control-system); (2) Tips about managing conflicts: [Is it really important to save django's migrations in a version control system? (`dev.to`)](https://dev.to/simo97/is-it-really-important-to-save-djangos-migrations-in-a-version-control-system--5d03); (3) Info on _squashing_ migrations: [How do you guys manage git + migrations? (`reddit`)](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/msm26e/how_do_you_guys_manage_git_migrations/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you didn't commit them to a VCS then what would happen is people would make potentially conflicting changes to the model.

When finally ready to deploy, you would still need django to make new migrations that would then merge everybodys changes together. And this just creates an additional unnecessary step that can introduce bugs.

You also are assuming everybody will always be able to work on an up to date version of the code which isn't always possible when you start working on branches that are not ready to be merged into mainline.

Comment: An example would be: person A created a branch from `master` and created a new migration `0010`, person B created a branch from `master` and created a new migration `0010`. A merged to develop earlier than B, when B pull the latest change and tried to merge his code to `master` he got a duplicate migration. If you don't track the migrations, B would be very confused.

Comment: OP suggests that pushing the models files, and generating migrations from those, should take care of this. I have wondered about this myself. Resolving inconsistent migrations, especially for shared branches and work in progress, has been an enormous waste of time. I see @alasdair's point below about automatic population (this is the one exception that makes sense to me, although it doesn't apply if you use factories instead of custom migrations). I would love to see better suggestions on best practices for avoiding migration conflicts, and/or better tools for resolving them.

Comment: for example, I just ran into a problem I have pretty frequently, where merge dependencies are missing when I try to migrate. The problem is, migrations files in separate apps are not always in sync across branches. The django errors don't give you the full path of the migrations file that caused the problem, only the number. #fail

Comment: @szeitlin - I would encourage you to ask a new question regarding your problem, feel free to refer to this question

Comment: Thanks ! I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550887/django-compare-model-code-to-database may help resolve my current issue, but I may still ask the larger question about how best to manage shared migrations. The answer below from @knbk re: testing also interests me.

Answer (score 8):

Migrations synchronize the state of your database with the state of your code. If you don't check in the migrations into version control, you lose the intermediate steps. You won't  be able to go back in the version control history and just run the code, as the database won't match the models at that point in time.

Migrations, like any code, should be tested, at the very least on a basic level. Even though they are auto-generated, that's not a guarantee that they will work 100% of the time. So the safe path is to create the migrations in your development environment, test them, and then push them to the production environment to apply them there.

Comment: Could you give examples of what kinds of tests you use for this? Do you check for data population?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, migrations in version control allows you to run them in production.

Secondly, migrations are not always automatically generated. For example, if you add a new field to a model, you might write a migration to populate the field. That migration cannot be re-created from the models. If that migration is not in version control, then no-one else will be able to run it.

Comment: Butt we can generate migrations in production as well and then apply these migrations. Is something wrong with this approach.?

Comment: Yes, in theory you could generate migrations in production (although not custom migrations, as I noted above). However, creating migrations in production could cause problems if you need to run the migration before updating the code (e.g. when adding a new model).

Comment: What @Alasdair is talking about is that you should be tracking them because there might be data migrations(custom migrations) you need. In some cases, people manually write a migration to achieve something like populate initial data, etc. If you don't save them in version control, you lost track of those steps.